# Let $\sigma\in{\rm Gal}(E/\Bbb Q)$ s.t. $\sigma(\alpha)=\bar\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in E$. Find ${\rm Inv}(\langle\sigma\rangle)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Question: Let $E$ be a splitting field of $x^4-2$.  Let $\sigma\in{\rm Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\bar\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in E$.  Find $\mathrm{Inv}(\langle\sigma\rangle)=\{\alpha\in E:\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha\}$.

Thoughts: We can determine the splitting field $E$ to be $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ (moreover, we can find that the order of this Galois group has to be $8$ and that the Galois group is iomorphic to the dihedral group of order $8$).  Now, all elements of $E$ are of the form $\alpha_1+\alpha_2\sqrt[4]{2}+\alpha_3\sqrt[4]{4}+\alpha_2\sqrt[4]{8}+\alpha_5i$ (I may have this wrong.).  So, an element of $E$ is in Inv$(\langle\sigma\rangle)$ whenever $\alpha_5=0$, thus Inv$(\langle\sigma\rangle)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, right?  Moeover, could we determine whether or not $\langle\sigma\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of ${\rm Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Is $\sigma = \phi$? Also, have you determined the order of $\sigma$ in $\text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo.  No, I haven't determined the order of $\sigma$ in the Galois group, only that the Galois group has order $8$.

Comment: For all $\alpha\in E$, $\sigma(\sigma(\alpha)) = \sigma(\bar{\alpha}) = \alpha$. So $\sigma$ has order two.

Comment: Okay!  But that is leading me to still believe that the answer should be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, since $[K:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})]=2$, right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Your definition of $\sigma$ assumes that $E$ is a subfield of $\Bbb C$. It might worth keeping in mind that $E$ can be defined as an abstract field, so that there is no canonical embedding of $E$ into $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Why haven't you corrected the typo, User7238?

Comment: @GerryMyerson fixed.  Sorry, I wasn't feeling well yesterday, and went to bed :)  It is corrected now.